# TCPclient.connected problem in Delphi - Indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tcpclient, indy, indy10

I am having problem with ***IdTCPclient.connected*** function from Indy in Delphi. I am using Indy10 and Delphi2010 environment. My problem is every time i check the TCP connection with ***IdTCPclient.connected***, it raises exception with these errors ***EidSocketError***, ***EidReadTimeOut***. Is there any way to disconnect and reconnect the connection? (like reset the connection).

Note: I set TCPClient.ReTimeout:= 30000;

The implemented coding for reset the connection is follow.

```
if IdTCPclient.connected then
  begin
  IdTCPclient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
  IdTCPclient.Disconnect;
  end;
sleep(1000);
try
  IdTCPclient.connect;
  except
    on E: Exception do 
      MessageDlg('Connecting Error: '+E.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
  end;
```

But some point, i get exception and it couldn't connect at all. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Should i do this?

- Disconnect first
- Clear input buffer
- Destroy TCPclient
- Re-create new TCPclient
- And then connect it again

If it is the case, can someone provide me a way how to do it properly?

Also, there is another function to re-connecting the TCP in my coding. It also gives me exception as well. I check the connecting before i send a message to TCP. If there is no connection, i reconnect for five times.

```
result := IdTCPclient.connected
if not result then
  begin
  for k:=0 to 4 do
    beign
    sleep(1000);
    try
      TCPclient.connect;
      except
        on E: Exception do 
          MessageDlg('Connecting Error: '+E.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
      end
    result := TCPclient.connected;
    if result then break;
    end;
```

With above two coding, program handles reconnecting and reset the connection pretty well. But some point the program cannot re-connect or reset the connection at all.

- What should i do when i get exception? Should i reconnect from exception?
- How do we build coding to check the connection regularly?
- How do we build coding to to get back the connection when it lost?

Kind regards,

Comment: may I suggest breaking up your question into several smaller questions that can be answered separately.

Comment: Could be similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890883/indy-error-socket-operation-on-non-socket-after-inactivity?noredirect=1#comment65145068_38890883

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Connected()` should not be raising any exceptions at all.  If it is, then it is likely a bug.  Please provide a stack trace showing that.

The best option is to simply avoid using `Connected()` whenever possible.  When you need to perform an I/O operation, just do so, and let Indy raise an exception if a failure occurs.  You can then handle it at that moment, eg:

```
try
  IdTCPClient.DoSomething...
except
  on E: EIdException do begin
    Reconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure Reconnect;
var
  k: Integer;
begin
  IdTCPClient.Disconnect;
  if IdTCPClient.IOHandler <> nil then
    IdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;

  for k := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    Sleep(1000);
    try
      IdTCPClient.Connect;
      Exit;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('Connecting Error: '+E.Message, mtError, [mbOk], 0);
        if k = 4 then
          raise;
      end;
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Similar to the OP, I'm seeing Indy10 Connected() raise an exception. Stack trace here http://i.imgur.com/F9ejbTl.png?1 No line numbers - sorry!

Comment: @Roddy: That does not make sense. `ReadDataFromSource()` is not called unless the socket is in a readable state first (`TIdSocketHandle.Readable()` returns True), which can only happen if the socket has actual data to read, or the connection has been *gracefully* disconnected by the peer. A `Receive()` should not fail on either of those conditions. What exception is actually being raised, and what socket error code is being reported?

Comment: `EIdSocketError`, 10054 connection reset by peer. It's definitely odd, but seems repatable. Indy is latest SVN from MJF. I have a 'working' connection, and then pull the plug. The client tries to send data and gets EIdSocketError (which is fine), but in the exception handler I call Connected() which also throws the same exception. Reading is handled by a different thread.

Comment: Ah, that explains why `Receive()` can fail. And it turn out that `TIdStackBSDBase.Receive()` is calling `CheckForSocketError()` but `TIdIOHandler` is expecting to handle the socket error instead (by letting `Connected()` discard it). I'll have to look into that, I think the `TIdStack` classes are calling `CheckForSocketError()` too much in general. In any case, you shouldn't be calling `Connected()` anyway. You already know the socket is not connected by virtue of the fact that you are getting an `EIdSocketError/10054` exception, so calling `Connected()` would be redundant.

Comment: @Remy Once (6 years ago) you said that Connected() from TIdTCPClient should not be raising any exceptions but it is. Is this an old still unresolved bug?

Comment: @Molochnik are you saying that the latest SVN revision is still raising the exception? I thought I fixed that years ago.

Comment: @Remy Yes, that's true, I always use your latest (almost) SVN version. Checking my old code I found that it always contains Connected in try-except blocks. Now I tried to eliminate them but exceptions still occur.

Answer (score 0):

before you connect  make sure that the passive Boolean of idftp is false
when you need file transfert change it to true with binary file option